# StaggeredGrid inside NestedScrollView not works

Tags: android, staggered-gridview, nestedscrollview

I have developed an Android Application in that I am using [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) for displaying Feeds. Normally its working fine, but when I putting in NestedScrollView, I can't see the data.

So, how to resolve this problem.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.acrobat.widgets.MySwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
                android:id="@+id/gvFeed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:column_count="2"
                app:column_count_portrait="2"
                app:item_margin="8dp" />
        </com.acrobat.widgets.MySwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Thanks.